# How to have child class contain pointer to base class

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I wanted to design class structure similar to following. The main idea is that Base class pointers must be updated when required. Similarly, we can have some unrelated operation on child classes.

I was wondering how should I redesign this to have polymorphism and encapsulation. It might be a very noob question but any help is appreciated.

I am not concerned about the memory leak in the snipped as the in actual code where this is being used the deletes are being done to avoid any issues.

What I want to ask is that is there a much better way of having the class structure similar as below, where instead of Child1 calling getBase to get Base class pointer, it could extend base class where the base class might have been already instantiated and child1 simply encapsulates and provide some functionality on top of it.

```
class Base {
private:
    int a;
    char b;
public:
    Base(int argA, char argB): a(argA), b(argB) {
    }


    char getChar() {
        return b;
    }

    int getInt() {
        return a;
    }

    void setChar(char foo) {
        b = foo;
    }

    void setInt(int foo) {
        a = foo;
    }
};

class Child1 {
private:

    Base *base;
public:
    Child1(PhysicalBlock *argBase) : base(argBase) {

    }

    Base *getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    uint64_t getSum() {
        int a = base->getInt();
        char b = base->getChar();
        return a + (int)b;
    }
};

class Child2 {
private:
    Base * base;
    double c;
public:
    Child2(Base * argBase) : base(argBase), c(0.0) {

    }

    Base *getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    double getDivision() {
        int a = base->getInt();
        char b = base->getChar();

        return (double) ((double)a + (double)b)/c;
    }
};

int bla(Child1 * c1)
{
    Base * b1 = c1->getBase();
    b1->setInt(55);
    b1->setChar('z');
    return c1->getSum();
}

int main()
{
    Base * b1 = new Base(1, 'a');
    Base * b2 = new Base(2, 'b');

    Child1 * child1 = new Child1(b1);
    Child2 * child2 = new Child2(b2);

    bla(child1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you show us `bla()`? Oh maybe it was for this `foo(child1);` --> `bla(child1);`? Also I don't understand what is your question. I mean I don't think that you are asking about the memory leaks of your program...

Comment: What are you *really* trying to achieve? This sounds somewhat like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)..

Comment: @gsamaras Added edit. Yes, it was a typo. I was referring to bla(child1)

Comment: `Child` is not really child in your example Because I don't see any inheritance.

Comment: In C++, a derived class (child) does _not_ need a reference to it's base class (i.e. it's parent).  The 'is-a relationship' means that the public and protected attributes of the parent are directly and easily accessed by the child ... no pointer needed.

Comment: In C++, the essence of polymorphism requires base class pointers.  The lack of a base pointer in the derived attributes does not prevent the use polymorphism (in the more conventional way).

Comment: In C++, the base class of a derived instance can not be changed (to another base class instance).  The data attributes of the base class can be changed, but the base and derived pairing are fixed for the instance lifetime.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain this. I had above class structure. But it seems unclean to me and was wondering if it could be cleaned up with OOP. The only problem I have is that Base object pointer is already initialized and now I want them to be encapsulated in form of Child1 or Child2 which on modification the initialized pointer data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean by `Child` is a `derived class` from a `base class` eg:

```
class Base{
    // some stuff here
};

class Child : public Base{
    // some code here
};
```

Now Child is really a child of class Base. Child can inherit `public` or `private` or `protected` each one has its use so read a useful book on OOP chapter inheritance.

- In the example I showed above You achieve `Is-a relationship`. So you can say: 
  `a man is a human, a dog is an animal...`.
- In your example you are achieving `has-a relationship`: So in your example class Child `has` an Object of class base. You can say `containment.
- I don't think that you need to contain a base class's object in the derived class. eg:

  ```
  class Base{};
  class Derived : protected Base{
      Base* pBase; // I don't think you need this.
  };
  ```
- You can access the base members (public, protected) form derived so there's no need to contain one.